# Php missing first row checkbox values in dynamic table, when inserting to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

**UPDATE, I have found answer, see below...**

Dynamic table of around 70 lines, user enters order size and selects a checkbox (which has a value) and submits to another table. Everything enters into mysql fine except the values of the checkboxes on the very first line, (they are always 0.000), acct id and order size for the first line enter fine, just checkboxes for some reason. Checkbox for lines 2-70 work just fine. I've totally confused myself, any ideas?

```
//php start
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form2")) {

mysql_select_db($database_demo_db01, $demo_db01);

//loop through the input values
for ($i = 0, $len = count($_POST['demo_acct_id']); $i < $len; $i++) {

//this trims the empty value from the lot_size column
if(trim($_POST['lot_size'][$i]) !== ''){        

   $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO demo_order (demo_acct_id_fk, demo_order_size,      demo_order_symbol, demo_order_bid, demo_order_ask) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['demo_acct_id'][$i], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['lot_size'][$i], "double"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['pair'][$i], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['checkbox'][$i], "double"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['checkbox2'][$i], "double"));


  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $demo_db01) or die(mysql_error());
    }//end loop

  $insertGoTo = "pairs_prices.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
}

<!--html-->
              <td><?php echo $row_p_p['pair']; ?>
                <input name="demo_acct_id[]" type="hidden" id="demo_acct_id" value="<?php echo $row_d_a['demo_acct_id']; ?>">
                <input name="pair[]" type="hidden" id="pair" value="<?php echo $row_p_p['pair']; ?>"></td>
              <td><label for="lot_size"></label>
                <input name="lot_size[]" type="text" id="lot_size" size="5"></td>
              <td><label for="checkbox"></label>
              <input type="hidden" name="checkbox[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="0">
          <input name="checkbox[<?php echo $i++; ?>]" type="checkbox" class="example" id="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_p_p['bid']; ?>">

            <?php echo $row_p_p['bid']; ?></td>
          <td><label for="checkbox2"></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="checkbox2[<?php echo $j; ?>]" value="0">
            <input name="checkbox2[<?php echo $j++; ?>]" type="checkbox" class="example" id="checkbox2" value="<?php echo $row_p_p['ask']; ?>" >
            <?php echo $row_p_p['ask']; ?></td>
```

**ANSWER:**
In the checkbox HTML, there is hidden input for each of the two checkboxes, I have this to check if the checkbox is clicked, so that only selected rows where the checkbox is checked gets submitted to db table. I have moved this hidden field from before the checkbox value to after the checkbox value. The checkbox value for the very first row is now returned to the db table.

Comment: Show us the first two lines from your HTML code

Comment: Which bit you want, the form tag or something else?

Comment: So these two lines: `<input name="checkbox[<?php echo $i++; ?>]" type="checkbox" class="example" id="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_p_p['bid']; ?>">` and `<input name="checkbox2[<?php echo $j++; ?>]" type="checkbox" class="example" id="checkbox2" value="<?php echo $row_p_p['ask']; ?>" >` return zero value, right ? `$_POST['checkbox'][0]` and `$_POST['checkbox2'][0]` are **set** but value is `0` ?

Comment: Are the `$i` and `$j` variables initialized ?

Comment: where the checkbox are. if you print out you table with php, then show the whole loop.

Comment: Yes John, I think prob is here, $j variable is not initialized, how to do this? But I'm confused as the values of this variable are captured through row 2-70! Newbie!

Answer (score 0):

only first line is having issue ?

```
for ($i = 0, $len = count($_POST['demo_acct_id']); $i < $len; $i++) {
```

Change it to

```
for ($i = 1, $len = count($_POST['demo_acct_id']); $i < $len; $i++) {
```

Comment: Arrays are always started with `0`. Read the question again. He sad, he want the first line, but for some reason, he does not get the checkbox of it.

Comment: Sorry, now this just misses the whole of the first line out. First line is not added at all to table.

Comment: @lolka_bolka its not array . it is for loop it can be started from any number. if  you dont know then dont simply vote down.

Comment: yes it is. There are 70 lines, and arrays in that like: `$_POST['demo_acct_id'][];` This is why he `count($_POST['demo_acct_id']);`. I know, $i start from anywhere what is less then the count, but you do not understand the question i think. Yoo suggest him to start from `$i = 1` what is skip the first line. His problem is to not receive the vale of the checkbox `in the first line`. So your solution is totally misslead him.

Comment: the question was updated later stage. so it was not my problem. anyway i need to rewrite the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$len = count($_POST['demo_acct_id']);

for ($i = 0, $i < $len; $i++) {

//this trims the empty value from the lot_size column
if(trim($_POST['lot_size'][$i]) !== ''){        

$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO demo_order (demo_acct_id_fk, demo_order_size,          demo_order_symbol, demo_order_bid, demo_order_ask) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['demo_acct_id'][$i], "int"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['lot_size'][$i], "double"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['pair'][$i], "text"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['checkbox'][$i], "double"),
               GetSQLValueString($_POST['checkbox2'][$i], "double"));


 $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $demo_db01) or die(mysql_error());
 }//end loop

$insertGoTo = "pairs_prices.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
 $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
 $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is here , You use same name input. Please remove first one

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="0">
```

. Its replacing your value to 0 .

```
 <input type="hidden" name="checkbox[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="0">
 <input name="checkbox[<?php echo $i++; ?>]" type="checkbox" class="example" id="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_p_p['bid']; ?>">
```

and remove

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox2[<?php echo $j; ?>]" value="0">
```

FROM

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox2[<?php echo $j; ?>]" value="0">
<input name="checkbox2[<?php echo $j++; ?>]" type="checkbox" class="example" id="checkbox2" value="<?php echo $row_p_p['ask']; ?>" >
```

Note:  if user does not checkd the checkbox that will not submit